# install packageのエラー

Tags: r

R初心者です。下記についてどなたか教えていただきく、宜しくお願い致します。
Rstuidoである解析のため、以下にある＜入力内容＞で、学習データの設定、グラフ化を行い、ARモデルを作ろうと入力しました。
グラフ化までは首尾よく動き出力されるのですが、最後の「ARモデル構築」のところで、以下のようなメッセージが出てエラーになってしまいます。

＜エラー内容＞

```
Error in auto.arima(learn_data, max.p = 10, max.q = 0, max.d = 2, max.P = 0,  : 
  could not find function "auto.arima"

Error: object 'ARmodel' not found
```

これはそもそも、forecastパッケージがインストールされていないということなのでしょうか？何度もトライしてもダメで、最初からRやRStuidoをインストールし直してダメなのです。ちなみに、他のパッケージは難なくインストールできて動いています。

＜入力内容＞

```
install.packages("forecast")
library(forecast)

input_data <- chap3_data

target <- 33

learn_data_start <- target-30
learn_data_end <- target-1

learn_data <- ts(input_data[learn_data_start:learn_data_end,2])

y <- as.numeric(input_data[target,2])

plot(learn_data)
diff(learn_data)
plot(diff(learn_data))

ARmodel <- auto.arima(learn_data,　←ここの部分以下がrunしてもエラーになる
                      max.p = 10,
                      max.q = 0,
                      max.d = 2,
                      max.P = 0,
                      max.Q = 0,
                      max.D = 0)

ARmodel
```

Comment: `install.packages("forecast", dependencies = TRUE)` として、依存パッケージ全てをインストールしてみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: 早速のコメント、誠にありがとうございます。確かに依存するパッケージが複数、一緒にインストールされたので、その上で同じようにトライしてみたのですが、やはりだめでした・・・。何か他のプログラムが干渉しているのでしょうか？